How do I show $p\equiv q$ for states $p,q$ of a DFSM?
Is my following approach correct?
What I need to prove:

Given $p$ and $q$ are any $2$ states of an arbitrary DFSM, $M$; to prove $p≡q$, I must show $p≡ₙq$ for any natural number $n$. That is, I must show $\delta(p,w)$ is accepted by $M$ iff $\delta(q,w)$ is accepted by $M$ for any $w\in\Sigma^*$ where $|w|$ is a natural number. To prove this, I proceed by induction on $|w|$.

Base case: I must show $p\equiv q$ for strings of length $0$. So let $|w|=0$, then necessarily $w=\varepsilon$. Now, I will assume $p=\delta(p,\varepsilon)$ is accepted by $M$ iff $q=\delta(q,\varepsilon)$ is accepted by $M$, otherwise $p\not\equiv q$ for strings of length $0$ so there would be nothing to prove. As the base case holds, I can now assume an induction hypothesis.
Induction Hypothesis: $p\equiv q$ and $p'=\delta(p,w)\equiv\delta(q,w)=q'$ for any word $w$, where $|w|\in\{0,1,2,3,...,n-1\}$.
Inductive Case: Let $w$ be any word such that $|w|=n$. Then there exists some $a\in\Sigma$ and some $x\in\Sigma^*$ such that $w=ax$ (so $|x|=n-1$). By my induction hypothesis, $p'=\delta(p,a)\equiv\delta(q,a)=q'$ since $|a|=1$. Applying the induction hypothesis again, $p''=\delta(p',x)\equiv\delta(q',x)=q''$ since $|x|=n-1$. So, it follows that $p\equiv q$ for strings of length $n$, as needed.

Corollary:
So if my proof is correct, can I then say $p\equiv q$, for any states $p$ and $q$ given:

$p$ is an accepting state iff $q$ is an accepting state, thus fulfilling the base case
For all $a\in\Sigma$, $\delta(p,a)$ is an accepting state iff $\delta(q,a)$ is an accepting state, thus fulfilling the inductive case.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use MathJax. Some of the formulas are broken (on my device). Also please specify the notation ($M$, $\delta$, etc.)

What are $M$, $p$, and $q$? At some point, you're going to needs specifics of them in your proof. (For instance, at the very least you're going to need that either $p$ and $q$ are both accepting states or that $p$ and $q$ are both non-accepting states).

@Magdiragdag $p$ and $q$ are any 2 states of an arbitrary DFSM, $M$. I have clarified the base case to reflect that $p$ and $q$ are both accepting or both rejecting for the sake of my proof, otherwise there would be nothing to prove since $p\not\equiv q$ for strings of length $0$ implies $p\not\equiv q$ for strings of any length.

But how could you prove that $p \equiv q$ for arbitrary $M$, $p$, $q$? That is simply not true.

@Magdiragdag No, that is not what I am saying; that is clearly incorrect. I am trying to prove, that given any DFSM, $M$, and any $2$ states $p,q\in M$ that
if $p\equiv q$ for strings of length 0 and ($p\equiv q$) for strings of length $1$, then  $p\equiv q$ for strings of any length. That is why in the base case of my inductive proof, I stated that $p\equiv q$ for strings of length $0$ is assumed, else there would be nothing to prove.

I'm still not sure what you're trying to prove. Obviously $(p \equiv_0 q \land p \equiv_1 q) \to p \equiv q$ is also, in general, not true; it is very simple to build a counterexample.

@Magdiragdag Then how do i prove $p≡q$? That is the title of my post, how do I know when they are equivalent for any length of strings?

Like I said, you need some particular property of $M$, $p$, $q$ (and $p \equiv_0 q \land p \equiv_1 q$ is not enough). You cannot expect to have $p \equiv q$ always.
